# for i in range(len(firstname)): print(firstname[0]) - How do i print this in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently studying Python coding and I can't wait to master it. I have two weeks now in and I'm doing some exercises. So that's why this question (and other's what I might ask in the future :D ) might be trivial for your.

So, the goal here's to ask first name and last name from the user. After that print first letter from the first name as many times there's characters in that name (Jack = 4*J) and last name in the reserved order (Dullname = emanlluD).

Well I nailed that part, but now I just can't find a resolution how do I print this all in the one line. Because first name comes from the list and the print is:

```
Give your first name: Jack
Give your last name: Dullname
J
J
J
J
emanlluD
```

when result should be Jack Dullname = JJJJ emanlluD.

```
firstname =  str(input("Give your first name: "))
lastname = str(input("Give your last name: "))

for i in range(len(firstname)):
    print(firstname[0])

def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]

output = reverse(lastname)

print(output)
```

The problem here is the For loop part. I now it should be function and result should be printed with second output, but I just can't figure out how .sort that result.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Whoa! That was fast! I really appreciate all the answers! My training code is now working!

Comment: You can use `*` on strings. Also print can take `end` as a keyword argument. Replace your loop with `print(firstname[0]*len(firstname), end=" ")`

Comment: Your edit suggests you haven't seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) yet.

Comment: I used @Tranbi resolution, but it's here in comment so I can't confirm it.

Comment: I happily copy my comment as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269904/13525512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from my comment:
You can use * on strings. Also print can take end as a keyword argument. Replace your loop with

```
print(firstname[0]*len(firstname), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply.

```
print(firstname[0] * len(firstname), lastname[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
firstname =  str(input("Give your first name: "))
lastname = str(input("Give your last name: "))

print(firstname[0] * len(firstname), lastname[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Terve Jyri,

You could do that with for-loop like this

```
for i in range(len(firstname)):
    print(firstname[0], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
firstname = str(input("Give your first name: "))
lastname = str(input("Give your last name: "))

def reverse(x):

    return x[::-1]


output = reverse(lastname)

print(firstname[0] * 4, output)
```

will give

```
Give your first name: Jack
Give your last name: Dullname
JJJJ emanlluD
```

Comment: Not everybody's first name has length 4

Answer (score 0):

You can either end the print with your choosing `print(firstname[0],end=' ') #space`.
or you can concat the first letter (With space) to the output:

```
firstname =  str(input("Give your first name: "))
lastname = str(input("Give your last name: "))

output=""
for i in range(len(firstname)):
    output+=firstname[0]+" "

def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]

output += reverse(lastname)

print(output)
```

Another option is to utilize python and get rid of the for loop:

```
firstname =  str(input("Give your first name: "))
lastname = str(input("Give your last name: "))

print(firstname[0] * len(firstname) + lastname[::-1]) #Repeath the first letter with the length of the firstname and concat the reversed lastname.
```

Answer (score 0):

I really learned to love string formatting with `f"{VARNAME}"`:

```
print(f"{firstname[0]*len(firstname)} {lastname[::-1]}")
```